# coding previous button for an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm new to programming in objective C so forgive me for this simple question that I'm about to ask.  I'm creating a quiz app which the array of questions and answers are in a property list. I was able to code a "next question" button but I'm not sure how to code a button go back to a previous question..  Can someone please help??

```
- (void)nextQuizItem
 {
if (self.quizIndex == 999) {
    self.quizIndex = 0;
    self.statusLabel.text = @"";
} else if ((self.quiz.quizCount-1) > self.quizIndex) {
    self.quizIndex++;
} else {
    self.quizIndex = 0;
    self.statusLabel.text = @"";
}

if (self.quiz.quizCount >= self.quizIndex + 1) {
    [self.quiz nextQuestion:self.quizIndex];
    self.questionLabel.text = self.quiz.quote;
    self.answer1Label.text = self.quiz.ans1;
    self.answer2Label.text = self.quiz.ans2;
    self.answer3Label.text = self.quiz.ans3;
    self.answer4Label.text = self.quiz.ans4;
} else {
    self.quizIndex = 0;
    [self quizDone];
}


========================

  - (void) nextQuestion: (NSUInteger) idx
  {
self.quote = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'",self.movieArray[idx][@"quote"]];

self.ans1 = self.movieArray[idx][@"ans1"];
self.ans2 = self.movieArray[idx][@"ans2"];
self.ans3 = self.movieArray[idx][@"ans3"];
self.ans4 = self.movieArray[idx][@"ans4"];
self.tip = self.movieArray[idx][@"tip"];

if (idx == 0) {
    self.correctCount = 0;
    self.incorrectCount = 0;
    self.tipCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Likewise write a new method for back navigation and instead of `self.quizIndex++;` write `self.quizIndex--;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)prevQuizItem
 {
if (self.quizIndex == 0) {
    self.quizIndex = 999;
    self.statusLabel.text = @"";
} else if (self.quiz.quizCount > self.quizIndex-1) {
    self.quizIndex--;
} else {
    self.quizIndex = 999;
    self.statusLabel.text = @"";
}

if (self.quiz.quizCount <= self.quizIndex - 1) {
    [self.quiz prevQuestion:self.quizIndex];
    self.questionLabel.text = self.quiz.quote;
    self.answer1Label.text = self.quiz.ans1;
    self.answer2Label.text = self.quiz.ans2;
    self.answer3Label.text = self.quiz.ans3;
    self.answer4Label.text = self.quiz.ans4;
} else {
    self.quizIndex = 999;
    [self quizDone];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Krunal.. what should be the prevQuestion method..  I added above what I have for the nextQuestion..  Please help and thank you so much

Comment: @Ray:If it helped then you should up vote or accept the answer , as you have not added detailed code so like nextQuizItem method inside that you have added nextQuestion method so i thought you have ready for prevQuestion also..

Comment: My apologies, it won't let me vote up because I need 15 reputations.  Im new to the site so Im not sure how all of this works. Your very helpful and I appreciate your hand..

Comment: Thank you again for all your help!! I edit my original post and added the nextQuestion method.  please take a look and tell me what the prevQuestion method should be..  Thank you so much!